# WordPress Meta Query LIKE Weird String/Hash

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I'm running a simple LIKE meta_query as follows:

```
$meta_query[] = array(
    'key'     => '_department',
    'value'   => sanitize_text_field( $_REQUEST['department'] ),
    'compare' => 'LIKE'
);
// push to main WP_Query here
```

What's odd though is if I dump the $wp_query->request part of the query it looks like so:

```
( mt2.meta_key = '_department' AND mt2.meta_value LIKE '{a4eeec5aa4c896cb300f5aab299d4336f74fcb91103252699f91d781f4df916a}residential-sales{a4eeec5aa4c896cb300f5aab299d4336f74fcb91103252699f91d781f4df916a}' )
```

See how the % have been replaced by a weird hash? This is the same for all LIKE lookups. I have no plugins active and can't find any reference to this in the codex.

Anyone seen this before?

Comment: Show the sanitize_text_field function

Comment: I guess this is not the correct code u working on? you compare by `=` how come it become `LIKE` ?

Comment: @cjmling You're absolutely right. Apologies. Have corrected.

Comment: @MIhai If I var_dump(sanitize_text_field( $_REQUEST['address_keyword'] )); I get the value I expect. Nothing out of the ordinary

Answer (score 3):

This is expected behaviour from [Wordpress 4.8.3](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2017/10/31/changed-behaviour-of-esc_sql-in-wordpress-4-8-3/) onwards because the esc_sql() function has been modified and now does md5 hashes of reserved characters.

```
echo esc_sql( "100%" );
// "100{9fa52f39262a451892931117b9ab11b5a06d3a15faee833cc75edb18b4411d11}"
```

This was done to fix a [pre-4.8.3 vulnerability](https://blog.ircmaxell.com/2017/10/disclosure-wordpress-wpdb-sql-injection-technical.html) to sql injection attacks.

You can get the value that was escaped with the following call if you need it:

```
echo $wpdb->remove_placeholder_escape( esc_sql( "100%" ) );
// "100%"
```